# powershell how do I Create/format a dynamic list from a group membership to use in a for each loop

Tags: powershell, variables, foreach, format

bit of a noob question.

I have the following cmd which grabs the server members of a group which I can copy into a text list.  however as the group changes I need to modify the text list manually.

```
Get-AdGroupMember -identity "Reboot 7pm" | Sort-Object | select name
```

when I have that output in a text list, the following works fine.

```
$listpath = "C:\Scripts\servers.txt"
[System.Collections.ArrayList]$list = @(Get-content $listpath)
foreach($ComputerName in $list) 
    {
    Get-Uptime -ComputerName $ComputerName
```

I want to know if it is possible to use a variable that I can use again in a for each loop.  I've tried to do so, however the format of the list is not the same when is goes into a variable, thus the function (get-uptime) against the server doesn't work,  anyone know what I can do to format the output so I only get the server name?
EG.

```
$WSUS_7PM = Get-AdGroupMember -identity "Reboot 7pm" | Sort-Object | select name 

PS C:\Windows\system32> $WSUS_7PM

name          
----          
AXXXXX003   
BXXXXX005   
CXXXXX006   
DXXXXX007   


PS C:\Windows\system32> foreach($Name in $WSUS_7PM) {Write-Host $Name} 
@{name=AXXXXX003}
@{name=BXXXXX005}
@{name=CXXXXX006}
@{name=DXXXXX007}
```

so when I run the same cmds as above modified with the variable instead of the text list, I get the following as the server name is obviously incorrect.

$listpath = $WSUS_7PM
[System.Collections.ArrayList]$list = @(Get-content $WSUS_7PM)
foreach($ComputerName in $list)
{
Get-Uptime -ComputerName $ComputerName

```
WARNING: Unable to connect to @{name=AXXXXX003}
WARNING: Unable to connect to @{name=BXXXXX005}
```

I hope that makes sense to someone, appreciate the help in understanding what the difference is in the object output.

Thanks
Alzoo

Answer (score 1):

When you use `Select-Object name` you are creating a list of objects with a name property. You can either expand it ahead of time

```
$WSUS_7PM = Get-AdGroupMember -identity "Reboot 7pm" | Sort-Object | Select-Object -ExpandProperty name
```

or reference the name property later

```
foreach($Name in $WSUS_7PM.name) {Write-Host $Name}
```

Comment: Thanks Doug, Legend! That worked almost perfectly :)   $WSUS_7PM.name didn't work, it came back empty..  but when I removed .name from the variable,  the list was formatted correctly.  I still dont know what the difference is with the -expandProperty option, but its what I needed.